# Audio Player - how to check player.src='/test.php' returning error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5-audio

I have added a audio player in html `<audio id="player"></audio>` and we have added a play button.

On click of play button we are hiding play button and showing loader and after response showing stop button.

```
var player = document.getElementById('player');
player.src ='/ajaxcall.php';
player.play();
```

From server side we are sending 'false' if exception. When exception the loader is contentiously loading. How we can detect the error is occurred in this?

Comment: Are you not able to check the ajax response for a non 200 code or for false being returned?

Comment: I am not able to check from this call.

Comment: Hook an `error` event handler to the `audio` element